# Play Framework and Slick project architecture

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, play-slick

I'm migrating an Application from Grails to Play Framework and i'm currently trying to figure out what's the best way of organizing the project structure.

I want to use Slick Codegen alongside with Flyway for Migrations, cause i want to keep a track of all the migrations that are being done (a solution similar to Rails Migrations would be perfect).

I see that Play Framework has the Play-Slick module but from what i've noticed, everything just happens like pure black-magic.

I saw an [example on GitHub](https://github.com/wsargent/play-slick-3.0) where Slick Modelling, Play Framework and Flyway Migrations are 3 separate SBT Modules, which makes perfect sense in case we ever want to move away from Play Framework.

Now, my questions is: What's the best architecture approach for a Play Framework App?

Note: I'm a newbie in Play Framework and Scala.

Comment: there are some additional ansers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616810/play-framework-2-5-x-scala-slick-implementation-style

Answer (score 1):

I did a post a while ago about using Play + slick + mysql. Is has the minimal structure to work, but the one I found more correct (I think this point will be subjective): http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/

or the source code at https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps

Comment: How do you handle migrations? Does Slick generate initial DDL and SQL Updates to the database? I'm looking for a Code First solution and Hibernate is just too complex and heavy for the job.

Comment: evolutions are sql based: https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps/blob/master/conf/evolutions/default/1.sql  or read it at http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/#add-database-evolution

Comment: Ok. What i currently do is use the Grails Database Migration Plugin. `grails dbm-gorm-diff` and i execute the generated SQL code manually on the database, because i believe that automations are bad. This is the scenario i wanted: Change the Model classes, generate the SQL Update Script against current Schema in the Database and execute it